# python docxtpl - cant create dynamic form

Tags: python, django, ms-word

I have been trying to create a dynamic table in word but the created file has all the contents except the list inside the options tag. I have tried a lot of stuff but can't get it to work.

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

from registration.models import stuff


def create_doc(options, model, file='resources/stuff.docx'):
    doc = DocxTemplate(file)
    log = stuff(options_object=model)
    log.save()
    l = []
    for i in range(1, len(options) + 1):
        x = {}
        x['number'] = i
        x['course'] = options[i - 1]
        l.append(x)
    context = {
        'name': model.name,
        'reg_no': model.regno,
        'roll_no': model.rollno,
        'rank': model.student_rank,
        'course': model.alloted_to,
        'cat': model.alloted_cat,
        'options': l
    }
    doc.render(context)
    doc.save(f'media/request_{model.rollno}.docx')
```

[The template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECH5i.png)
[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV8cs.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using a different name than "options". I'm guessing it messed with the parameter that was being passed somehow and caused the issue.